# enp3s0: link is not ready

Tags: fedora, ipv6, dmesg

I've some strange messages in the `dmesg` output:

```
[    7.588762] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[    7.589616] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[    7.591897] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[    7.827124] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
```

Generally I have no need in ipv6 and it is disabled:

```
~$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And the `eno1` is even unplugged. So why I see these messages in the `dmesg` output and how can I fix it?

Comment: Apparently this particular error message can be misleading. For example, [this is a case](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/138943/solved-raspberry-pi4-drops-to-maintenance-mode-during-boot) where the cause of a similarly-worded error was a drive listed in `/etc/fstab` that failed to mount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feel free to double-check `ip -6 addr`.  But those specific messages tend to be a mystery and might be best ignored :).

I have left IPv6 enabled (but no IPv6 router or anything) and I get

```
[    2.229087] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    4.445878] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

From which I conclude this relates to IPv6 duplicate-address-detection (DAD), for stateless-address-autoconfiguration (SLAAC) of link-local addresses (LLA).  I.e. picking a random local address, it has to check it's not used in the local network & wait a couple of seconds to receive that result.

```
$ ip -6 addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::12bf:48ff:fe79:f3a1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip -6 route
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

Without the `becomes ready` message or any IPv6 addresses, you sound pretty safe!

### Make it go away

But maybe you desperately need to reduce attack surface and/or distrust running any ipv6 code at all.  In that case there's a further disable option you can configure on the kernel command line.  E.g. by following your distro documentation to set it in GRUB.  The option is `ipv6.disable=1`.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPv6#Disable_functionality